# Get all LCR for table

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

I need to create replication process for table table1. So I decide to create queue of LCR's then transfer them via web connection to another server. Now I try to figure out how to get LCR's for all dml performing on table1?

Comment: What language are you using?  Is this all PL/SQL and DB Links?

Comment: @Nick I use PL/SQL but cannot use DBLINK only web connection

Comment: So you can only use HTTP?